# How to run a cmd command from bat file?

Tags: batch-file, autorun

I need to run this command in the command prompt automatically:

```
msiexec /i "My application"/qn
```

How can I write a batch file to do this?

Comment: "automatically" based on what trigger? Booting? Logging in? Defined time?

Comment: i mean can i run the batch from Autorun file>

Comment: just put your batchfile into the "startup" folder: `"%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"`

Comment: Can i do this from Autorun.inf ?

Answer (score 0):

Batch files are, for all intents and purposes, just lists of cmd commands. Just take that command, paste it into notepad, and save it with a .bat extension.

It's generally considered good practice to start the batch script with the line `@echo off` so that the lines of the script don't display as they're being executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
msiexec/i "My application"/qn
```

To run the batch file when the VM user logs in:

Drag batch file itself to Start - All Programs - Startup. Now when you login as that user, it will launch the batch file.

you may find the  [Batch HowTos](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchhowto.php) helpful.

<kbd>**Examples:**</kbd>  see [Link](http://ss64.com/nt/msiexec.html)

```
Install:
msiexec /i "C:\Install\ss64app.msi"

 UnInstall:
msiexec /uninstall "{5AFF6499-63BA-4A36-83B2-8D256404AC3D}" /log "C:\install\ss64app.txt"
```

Autorun

```
1. create text file

2. edit with Notepad 

[autorun] 
icon=drive.ico
open=launch.bat
open=launch.bat
[autorun]     
open=\folder1\runinstallers.bat
open=\folder2\PLSetup_2.exe  

3. save the file as Autorun.inf
4. copy the Autorun.inf to the root folder of your CD-ROM
```

Comment: Ok,so how to set the file path?

Comment: look at the answer `to auto run move batch file in Startup folder`

Comment: [Click on info](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpCmdLineMSI.htm)

Comment: A little question: 01.Can i Run this automatically from Autorun file?  02.Can add this file to startup from Autorun file?

Comment: Oh i  saw that.So how to add my batch file to startup automatically

Comment: usually autorun from removable media is disabled by default for security reasons.